# GLSL vs Multitexture in Blender 2.79

Tags: texturing

I use Blender 2.79 and I want to know the difference between Multitexture and GLSL shading mode and which one must I used for a better result.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18950395/fixed-function-vs-shader-based